# How to change Text in a Link if Link is active?

Tags: php, jquery, html, hyperlink

I have a .php file that structures my slideshow. In that slideshow I have a little "+" that – onClick – toggles down a div with more information. I just don't know how to manage that, if the div is toggled down, so the link is "active" the "+" is changed to a "-" or a "x"?

Can someone help me with that?

```
"<div id='dialog-box-text'><a href='#' onclick=\"$('#dialog-toggle').toggle();\" style='display: block;'>[+]</a><div id='dialog-toggle'>"
```

This is my little line of code, that manages this "effect"

Thank you for any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"<div id='dialog-box-text'><a href='#' onclick=\"$('#dialog-toggle').toggle();if($(this).text()=='[+]')$(this).text('[x]');else $(this).text('[+]')\" style='display: block;'>[+]</a><div id='dialog-toggle'>"
```

Comment: If I paste it in, the link unfortunately does not work anymore… Do you have any Idea why??

Comment: It works for me when I use this string with the echo command.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to post this as a comment but my rep is not high enough.

Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/s1gzxsb7/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#close").on("click", function(){
        if($(this).text()=="[+]"){
           $(this).text("[x]");
        }else{
           $(this).text("[+]");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, exactly! So how can I integrate this in my .php file?

Comment: You have to have jQuery included first so: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your head tags. Then, you add the code within <script> "code here" </script>

Answer (score 0):

I had this stored away - not sure if it would help:

http://codepen.io/CalvT/pen/JoOJJB

The Javascript of it is the following:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
  $('.wrap, a').toggleClass('active');

  return false;
});
```